# Retornando diferença entre datas com dias e meses

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

Estou desenvolvendo uma função em C# que calcule os juros aplicado a uma determinada conta. para isso é necessário saber a diferença correta entre os dias e meses.

Como é possível executar uma função em C# que retorne o numero de dias e meses dentre uma data, Por exemplo: Tem-se uma data inicial 18/07/2017 e uma data final 29/08/2017

Então 29/08/2017  - 18/07/2017 Resultaria em uma string "Mês:1 e Dias:11"

Se no caso o juros for de 0,33 ao mês, então 1 mês seria cobrado os 0,33 de juros e os 11 dias acrescentaria os 0,121. porém para isso seria necessário uma aplicação que resultaria corretamente os dias e meses.

Se eu uso `Subtract` só é possível retornar o numero de dias, então eu poderia pegar todos os dias e dividir por 30, porém nem todos os meses tem 30 dias. Então qual é a forma mais correta de realizar essa função?

```
 public CalcularValor(decimal ValorASerPago, string pDataVencimento, decimal Juros, decimal Multa){

     DateTime DateVencimento, DataAtual = DateTime.Now;
     DateTime.TryParse(pDataVencimento+" "+"23:59:59", out DateVencimento);   


     if (DataAtual > DateVencimento) { // Caso a conta esteja vencida é acrescentado os juros e multa

          decimal ValorDaMulta = (ValoraSerPago*Multa)/100;
          int TotalDia = (DataAtual.Subtract(DateVencimento)).Days; 
          // Como saber quantos meses e dias restam para aplicar o valor correta referente ao juros de acordo com o tempo de vencimento?

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Depois de edições e melhor entendimento do problema boa parte da resposta não serve para a solução, é muito mais simples do que parecia</sup>

Quando cria a diferença entre duas datas ([`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0)) recebe um intervalo de tempo, ou seja, um [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Daí é só dividir pelo número de dias.

```
(int)(timespan.Days/30.436875)
```

Se quer pegar os dias restantes basta obter o resto:

```
timespan.Days - ((int)(timespan.Days/30.436875) * 30.436875)
```

Se quiser anos:

```
(int)(timespan.Days/365.2425)
```

Isso pode não dar o resultado esperado em todas situações, mas precisaria ter critérios claros de como lidar com cada situação, o que não tem na pergunta.

Se a pergunta estivesse mais caprichada eu capricharia mais.

Ou pode usar a [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) que tem tudo pronto.

Também tem uma [resposta no SO onde cria um tipo `DateTimeSpan`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9216404/221800) que calcula isto segundo o critério adotado por aquele programador.

```
public struct DateTimeSpan
{
    private readonly int years;
    private readonly int months;
    private readonly int days;
    private readonly int hours;
    private readonly int minutes;
    private readonly int seconds;
    private readonly int milliseconds;

    public DateTimeSpan(int years, int months, int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
    {
        this.years = years;
        this.months = months;
        this.days = days;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
    }

    public int Years { get { return years; } }
    public int Months { get { return months; } }
    public int Days { get { return days; } }
    public int Hours { get { return hours; } }
    public int Minutes { get { return minutes; } }
    public int Seconds { get { return seconds; } }
    public int Milliseconds { get { return milliseconds; } }

    enum Phase { Years, Months, Days, Done }

    public static DateTimeSpan CompareDates(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        if (date2 < date1)
        {
            var sub = date1;
            date1 = date2;
            date2 = sub;
        }

        DateTime current = date1;
        int years = 0;
        int months = 0;
        int days = 0;

        Phase phase = Phase.Years;
        DateTimeSpan span = new DateTimeSpan();
        int officialDay = current.Day;

        while (phase != Phase.Done)
        {
            switch (phase)
            {
                case Phase.Years:
                    if (current.AddYears(years + 1) > date2)
                    {
                        phase = Phase.Months;
                        current = current.AddYears(years);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        years++;
                    }
                    break;
                case Phase.Months:
                    if (current.AddMonths(months + 1) > date2)
                    {
                        phase = Phase.Days;
                        current = current.AddMonths(months);
                        if (current.Day < officialDay && officialDay <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(current.Year, current.Month))
                            current = current.AddDays(officialDay - current.Day);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        months++;
                    }
                    break;
                case Phase.Days:
                    if (current.AddDays(days + 1) > date2)
                    {
                        current = current.AddDays(days);
                        var timespan = date2 - current;
                        span = new DateTimeSpan(years, months, days, timespan.Hours, timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds);
                        phase = Phase.Done;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        days++;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return span;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/DateTimeSpan.cs).

---

Com edições na pergunta ficou claro que o problema era outro. Vamos analisar o código postado e melhorá-lo:

```
public CalcularValor(decimal ValorASerPago, string pDataVencimento, decimal Juros, decimal Multa){
```

O código não retorna nada? Podia ter usado os nomes das variáveis em minúsculo, né?

Não tem jeito desta data ser de outro tipo? Eu sei o erro já está em outro lugar, mas não iseria o caso de arrumar isso?

```
DateTime.TryParse(pDataVencimento + " "+"23:59:59", out DateVencimento);
```

De que adianta usar o `TryParse()` se não vai verificar se a conversão deu certo? O dado pode vir errado ou é fonte garantida que tem uma data válida?

Em C# 7 pode usar `DateTime.TryParse(pDataVencimento + " "+"23:59:59", out var DateVencimento);` e nem precisa declara a variável antes.

```
if (DataAtual > DateVencimento) {
```

Isso me preocupa um pouco, mas na sua rotina não deve causar problema.

```
decimal ValorDaMulta = ValoraSerPago / 100 * Multa;
```

Melhor assim. Estou considerando que `multa` é um percentual.

O que precisa saber é o número de dias e não o número de meses. A pergunta original nem fazia sentido. Juros são diários, você tem que multiplicar o número de dia que está atrasado.

Pior, toda esta conta está errada, deveria ser algo assim:

```
public decimal CalcularValorTotal(decimal valorAPagar, string dataVencimento, decimal juros, decimal multa) {
    var vencimento = DateTime.Parse(dataVencimento);
    var hoje = DateTime.Now;
    if (hoje > vencimento) {
        var valorMulta = valorAPagar / 100 * Multa;
        var valorJuros = (hoje.Date - vencimento.Date).Days * juros;
        return valorAPagar + valorMulta + valorJuros;
    }
    return valorAPagar;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/CalculateInterested.cs).

Se tiver que tratar o erro, o método precisa ser bem mudado para lidar com isso, segui a linha que não precisa, mas não posso afirma isso.

Comment: Porque na função (int)(timespan.Days/30.436875) o valor de 30 tem as casas decimais? essa método retornaria o resultado correto levando em consideração que nem todos os meses tem 30 dias?

Comment: Correto, dependendo do critério, porque ele lineariza os meses, o que não é bem verdade.

Comment: Fiz uma edição na pergunta, para você fica mais claro? Com esse método seria possivel resolver o problema em questão?

Comment: Cadê seu código? Onde está seu problema específico? Colocar mais informações irrelevantes não ajuda ficar mais claro. O problema está claro, o que não tem é detalhes. Então a resposta tem alguns detalhes, mas não tantos quanto poderiam se você colocasse os detalhes que está fazendo. Você só encheu linguiça. Porém essa informação mostra que seu problema é outro completamente diferente do que está na pergunta, não é assim que se calcula juros. Mesmo esse problema de calcular juros que é outra pergunta diferente não tem critérios para saber a forma exata de calculá-lo.

Comment: A parti da aplicação referente ao juros não é problema, e sim uma forma exata de retornar a data correta em meses e dias.

Comment: Se você parte do problema errado, a solução será errada.

Comment: Então você pode me indicar algum tutorial ou algo relacionado para eu conseguir resolver essa questão de maneira correta

Comment: Não existe algo assim, talvez seja o caso de abrir outra pergunta, mas precisa dar detalhes, mostrar o que está fazendo. Melhorei a resposta e esta é a solução real.